# Android, write image into internal memory

Tags: android, image, file

I have gotten this message when I try to save an imagen file ...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logocte1 (Read-only file system)
```

My method ...

```
public static String saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    String stored = null;


    File file = new File(filename)  ;
    if (file.exists())
        return stored ;

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return stored;
   }
```

I want to write the file INTO internal menory ... I don't have external memory in my pone.

Answer (score 0):

> I have gotten this message when I try to save an imagen file

You cannot write to arbitrary locations. Please use methods like `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()` for directories that you can write to.

> I don't have external memory in my pone.

Most likely, you do. [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not the same as [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), and neither of those are the same as [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: how use getFilesDir ?  Context.getFilesDir() ?

Comment: @user3285457: `Context` is a superclass of classes like `Activity` and `Service`, so you usually call `getFilesDir()` on one of those.

Comment: Oks ... I read about "external storage" ... now I'm working with File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and I have gotten the message error .... /mnt/sdcard/images/logocte1.jpg (Permission denied) and I have in manifest...  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @user3285457: Did you create the `images/` directory?

Comment: Yes ..folder.mkdir(); File file = new File(folder, filename + ".jpg") ;

Comment: @user3285457: If you are testing on an emulator, you need to configure that emulator with external storage (unfortunately referred to in the AVD Manager as an "SD card"). If you are testing on a device, I suppose it is conceivable that you truly do not have external storage, though that is *very* unusual. You might examine your device/emulator in DDMS' File Manager (via the Eclipse perspective or the Android Device Monitor from Android Studio) and see what shows up in `/mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: The /mnt/sdcard it's empty